# Как убрать пустое поле вверху в PhotoView?

Tags: java, android

Загружаю картинку в компонент PhotoView. Получаются пустые поля над и под картинкой.

Как их убрать?
Делаю так:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/ll_scr1"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/ivScr1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/wv_scr1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` добавить для PhotoView

Comment: Это не помогло :(

Comment: А если добавить `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` к PhotoView?